# Julia -- no method matching +(::Float64, ::Vector{Float64})

Tags: julia

I started out without dot-notation, and after adding it I am still getting an error.
What will make this work?
Is there a book or web-url that descripes the syntax rules for solving this?

I am running this in Julia  Version 1.9.3 (2023-08-24)
using VSCode Version: 1.83.0
on Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
tkx, Paul

```
# Failing.jl -- example
using DataFrames
using Random

Random.seed!(1234)

start_year = 2015
end_year   = 2020
n_steps = length(start_year:end_year)

thisResult =  DataFrame(years = [start_year:1:end_year;],
                        net_output = rand(n_steps))

discount2pct = DataFrame(pct = fill(0.02,n_steps)[:,1])  
colName = "Disc_2pct"

thisResult[!, "$colName"] .=   thisResult[:, :net_output] ./ ((1.0 + discount2pct[:, :pct]) .^ (2015 - thisResult[:,years]))
```

> > ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching +(::Float64, ::Vector{Float64}) For element-wise addition, use broadcasting with
> > dot syntax: scalar .+ array      Closest candidates are:   +(::Any,
> > ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...)    @ Base operators.jl:578   +(::T, ::T) where
> > T<:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64}    @ Base float.jl:408
> > +(::Union{Float16, Float32, Float64}, ::BigFloat)        @ Base mpfr.jl:423   ... Stacktrace:   [1] top-level scope   @
> > c:\Failing.jl:13

Comment: it seems like you're wanting something like this: `thisResult[:, :net_output] ./ ((1.0 .+ discount2pct[:, :pct]) .^ (2015 .- thisResult[:, :years]))`

Comment: though without a desired output it's hard to say

Comment: @Mark this code has been abstracted from the real problem to isolate the failure.  When I put your solution into the real code it gives good data.

Answer (score 3):

Take note that `discount2pcd[:, :pct]` and `thisResult[:,years]` are both `Vector{Float64}`. You cannot simply add a scalar to vectors in Julia so you also need to use the broadcast dot notation.

```
(1.0 .+ discount2pct[:, :pct]) .^ (2015 .- thisResult[:,years])
```

Comment: MANY thanks for the quick solution.  IT WORKS in the real code with real data.  I had overlooked the two additional operators, and the colon in front of :years

Comment: ERROR: UndefVarError: `years` not defined